# Highlight text in Silverlight (background colour yellow)

Tags: silverlight, richtextbox

I need to highlight text in a Silverlight Textblock or RichTextBox. I've tried just adding tags to the text run of the RTB but they simply show up in the text like:

```
Some <Bold>text</Bold> in a RTB
```

I've tried just selecting the text like this:

```
myRTB.Selection.Select(textPtr1, textPtr2);
```

but that **highlights in the standard blue-ish colour**. I need to make the background colour yellow, but looks like I can only change the Foreground colour of a Run. Why is that, and any ideas for me?

UPDATE:

I've tried using just a TextBlock with a value converter that adds a Run like this:

```
return String.Format("<Run Foreground=\"Red\">{0}</Run>", value.ToString());
```

but still the TextBlock just shows the tags, not the formatted text.

Comment: If I'm not wrogn: <Run FontWeight="Bold">your text</Run>

Comment: Adding any xml tags to the text that the RTB is bound to just causes the tags to show in the text in the RTB.

Comment: Still looking for a solution to highlighting text programmatically in Silverlight. Any takers?

Comment: Sorry for being this late... If you are adding text in code you can add this "Runs" to the "Inlines" property for the Textblock.

Comment: I tried adding a Run via the binding converter - see above. That doesn't work though - the tags just show literally. I'll look at the InLines property.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to highlight text in a Silverlight Textblock

You can wrap your `textBlock` with a border, and change the border color on `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave`.

**XAML**:

```
 <Border x:Name="myTxtBorder" MouseEnter="myTxtBorder_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="myTxtBorder_MouseLeave">
        <TextBlock Text="Hover me and yellow you'll see!"/>
  </Border>
```

**Code behind:**

```
Private Sub myTxtBorder_MouseEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs)
        myTxtBorder.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow)
    End Sub

    Private Sub myTxtBorder_MouseLeave(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs)
        myTxtBorder.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
    End Sub
```

Comment: I only need to highlight certain words though - so I would need to add the border to these specific words on the fly at runtime. How can I do that?

Comment: @Graeme: Using the border approach, you'll need to extract the words you want to highlight into a separate textBlock and wrap it with border. If you have lots of text, you'll end up with lots of controls, which is not a good thing. How many text are you handling?

Comment: The textblock is in a listbox and each one will contain a couple of hundred words. Might be 20 items in the list, each with 2 or 3 occurrences of the word to hightlight.

Answer (score 0):

The Liquid.RichTextBox might help you.

http://vectorlight.net/silverlight/controls/rich_textbox.aspx